# Generate only positive random numbers and sort them

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to generate positive numbers and sort them ascending order, without using `arrays.sort`.

This code, asks for how many random numbers and then sort them and print it out. My code asks for how many and is printing out one less than the given.

For example  when i ask for 2, it prints out only one. Unable to find the mistake or error.

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want? ");
        int howMany = in.nextInt();
        int[] myArray = getRandomArray(howMany);

    }

    /* public static int bsearch(int[] arr, int key)
            {

            }*/
    public static int[] getRandomArray(int howMany) {
        int[] returnMe = new int[howMany]; // Assume size >= 0
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            returnMe[i] = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1;
            System.out.print(returnMe[i] + " ");
            for (i = 1; i <= returnMe.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < returnMe.length; j++) {
                    int tmp = 0;
                    if (returnMe[i] > returnMe[j]) {
                        tmp = returnMe[i];
                        returnMe[i] = returnMe[j];
                        returnMe[j] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnMe;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing the `i` in your loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {//loop 1
    ...
    for (i = 1; i <= returnMe.length; i++) {//loop 2
    //--------------------------------^^^
    //When you get out from this loop, the i is > then the original i
```

To avoid this problem, use another variable, for example your code should be like this :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {//loop 1
    ...
    for (int k = 1; k <= returnMe.length; k++) {//loop 2
    //-------^------^---------------------^
```

and the program will generate what you want.

Comment: I tried doing `(i = 0 ; i < returnMe.length; i++) ` for loop two, it still does the same @YCF_L

Comment: no @karthika don't use this instead use another variable, check my edit i already post all the solution

Comment: Oh alright, but now it is not sorting it sir @YCD_L

Comment: now it depend of your algorithm, maybe i changed a lot in your program, so check it carefully, maybe in place of `i` i used `k`